# Haskell - Applicative/Monad instances

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative

I've seen that the type of `pure 1` is `(Num a, Applicative f) => f a`, which is quite obvious. 
So if I would like to make it a `Maybe Int`:

```
Prelude> pure 1 :: Maybe Int
Just 1
```

What about this?

```
Prelude> pure 1
1
Prelude> return 1
1
```

What is going on? Why doesn't it complain about not knowing which instance to choose??

**Edit**

I think that this behaviour actually has nothing to do with monads or applicatives, but this was the context I came to it...

Comment: see `return True` in [I/O actions at the prompt](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a peculiarity of ghci. It has special handling for `IO` actions, which aren't just “computed” and printed (you can't print an IO action anyway), but executed and *the result*<sup>†</sup> printed. So,

```
Prelude> pure 1 :: IO Integer
1
```

As per behzad.nouri's comment, [here's the relevant manual section](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html).

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Provided it's `IO a` with `Show a` and not `a~()`, otherwise *only* the action is executed.</sub>

Comment: So, actually it has something to do with Monad/Applicative instances, because IO is a Monad/Applicative/Functor... Am I right??

Comment: Well, if IO weren't applicative then this clearly wouldn't work. I'm not sure how GHCi decides to interpret an expression as `IO`; apparently it first tries to unify any type with `IO a` and only if that fails goes the print-only route. This wouldn't really have anything to do with monads.